# Submit form with different submit buttons

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

I have a form that can be sent with different submit buttons:

```
<form id="my_form">
  <button type='submit' name='first_button'>
  <button type='submit' name='second_button'>
<form>
```

I have created handler onclick via jquery for submit buttons which prevent default action, and doing some work but then I need to submit this form.

If I just simulate click on button - all actions triggered to onclick works once again.

If I use, the following code, it will just activate submit of first button:

```
$("#my_form").get(0).submit();
```

So how can I send the form differently according to the button that was clicked?

Comment: share the event handler

Answer (score 0):

Prevent default form submit.

```
$("#my_form").submit(function(e){
    return false;
});
```

// adding `id` or `class` to btns is better..
// add differnt event listners to buttons which will perform the submit action

```
$("[name='first_button']").on('click', function(){...});

$("[name='second_button']").on('click', function(){...});
```

Comment: It doesn't address my problem. As I said, if I just simulate click on button - all actions triggered to onclick works once again. So I need to simulate a submit, not a click.

Comment: @Jeremie you can manually submit your form inside those listners right?

Comment: Did you prevent the default form submit? otherwise because your button type is `type='submit'` the form will get submitted again

Comment: @Jeremie or else if you are saying that your button click handler gets executed twice..then `off` the listner before `on`

Comment: Yes the event default behavior is properly disabled and yes the form can be submitted manually

Comment: So the question is simply: how can I access the second button using #(my_form).get(0).submit()

Comment: @Jeremie still didnt get it. Did you mean you want to know which button triggered the submit?

Comment: No, I want to submit the form using the second button, but not with onclick